# Nextjs: Component is not updating the DOM when cookie is removed but updating when cookie is added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, conditional-rendering

I have added a `<Navbar />` component over `<Component {...pageProps} />` in `_app.js`. When login is successful, I add a cookie `Cookies.set('isLoggedIn', true,..)` and it updates the DOM from showing `Login` and `Signup` to showing `Logout` button on the navbar. But when I click `Logout`, this `isLoggedin` cookie is deleted and, therefore, the DOM should now show `Login` and `Signup` again on the navbar. Instead, it keeps showing `Logout`.

So, how do I refresh the DOM so that it shows `Login` and `Signup` when the cookie is deleted?

Login code, it successfully sets the cookie:

```js
axios
  .post(url, data, { withCredentials: true }, (Headers = config))
  .then(Cookies.set('isLoggedIn', true, { secure: true }, { sameSite: 'lax' }));
```

Logout code and Code for DOM changes:

```js
const isLoggedIn = Cookies.get('isLoggedIn') ? true : false;

const handleLogout = () => {
  axios
    .post(devURL, (Headers = config), { withCredentials: true })
    .then(Cookies.remove('isLoggedIn'));
  ...
};


return ({
  isLoggedIn === false ? (
    <div className={styles.authOpt}>
      <Link href="/login">
        <button className={styles.authButton}>Login</button>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/signup">
        <button className={styles.authButton}>SignUp</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className={styles.authOpt}>
      <button className={styles.authButton} onClick={handleLogout}>
        Log out
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

It's most likely an **hydration** issue because, the changed state is coming through the console.log() output but it's not changing the DOM.

Comment: To reflect `isLoggedIn` value changes on the UI move it to state (using React's [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)) and update the state accordingly when needed.

Comment: Tried with `useState` but it's the same!

Answer (score 0):

React Components can't be re-rendered without changes in `props` / `state`.

So, your `isLoggedIn` variable must be part of the state of this component.

```js
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(Cookies.get('isLoggedIn') ? true : false);
// --------------------------------------------^ initial value of the state retrieved from the cookies

const handleLogout = () => {
  axios.post(devURL, (Headers = config), { withCredentials: true }).then(() => {
    Cookies.remove('isLoggedIn');
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
    // -----^
  });
  ...
};


return ({
  isLoggedIn === false ? (
    <div className={styles.authOpt}>
      <Link href="/login">
        <button className={styles.authButton}>Login</button>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/signup">
        <button className={styles.authButton}>SignUp</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className={styles.authOpt}>
      <button className={styles.authButton} onClick={handleLogout}>
        Log out
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: I had used this method previously and it had some issues of it's own. DOM changes reflected after page refreshing, etc. So I,m now using `Context`.